# Program Crash - probably a memory retain misuse

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of Objective-C objects that is to be sorted on a field of the object.  I use a simple selection sort since the array is small.  The sort works and the correct data is in the array, but after adding about 3 or 4 objects to the array and resorting each time it crashes. 
Any help would be appreciated. The error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS Thanks in advance.  The code follows:

```
TopTenDataClass *temp1 = [[TopTenDataClass alloc] init];
TopTenDataClass *temp2 = [[TopTenDataClass alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < [topTenDataArray count]; i++)
{
    int minIndex = i;
    for (int j = i; j < [topTenDataArray count]; j++)
    {
        temp1 = [topTenDataArray objectAtIndex:minIndex];
        temp2 = [topTenDataArray objectAtIndex:j];
        if ( temp2.timeInSeconds < temp1.timeInSeconds)
            minIndex = j;
    }
    [topTenDataArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:minIndex withObjectAtIndex:i];
}
[temp2 release]; [temp1 release];
```

Comment: Interestingly, memory leaks rarely cause crashes, that is one reason they are so hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that inside of your loop you are changing the values of `temp1` and `temp2`.  When you release them after the loop completes, you are not releasing the objects that you created before the loop started.  Instead you are attempting to release some other object that you did not alloc/init (in this part of the code).  Probably that is what is causing your crash.

I'd suggest trying something like:

```
TopTenDataClass *temp1 = nil;
TopTenDataClass *temp2 = nil;
for (int i = 0; i < [topTenDataArray count]; i++)
{
    int minIndex = i;
    for (int j = i; j < [topTenDataArray count]; j++)
    {
        temp1 = [topTenDataArray objectAtIndex:minIndex];
        temp2 = [topTenDataArray objectAtIndex:j];
        if ( temp2.timeInSeconds < temp1.timeInSeconds)
            minIndex = j;
    }
    [topTenDataArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:minIndex withObjectAtIndex:i];
}
```

You don't need to assign a new object instance to `temp1` and `temp2` before the loop, because you just overwrite their values inside your loop.

Do also note that if `topTenDataArray` has only a single element in it your code will call `[topTenDataArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:0 withObjectAtIndex:0]`, which may also be a problem (the [API docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) don't say that you can't exchange an object with itself, but they don't say that you can, either).

Comment: Amazing, there is less code in the version that works!  That happens often, more code == more chances to make a mistake.

Comment: wroth - Thanks SO MUCH - that was it.  Appreciate the help